# How to render custom icons (not Office UI Fabric Icons) in INavLink in react application

Tags: reactjs, icons, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

Am using Nav from office-ui-fabric-react and rendering a Nav bar with icons like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/inavlink?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#icon. My requirement is to render some custom icon in the Nav bar. The icon property expects a string and am only able to use the icons from here https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/ with thier friendly names,

```
          //Doesn't render icon
          {
            name: "App details",
            url: "http://msn.com",
            key: "key1",
            target: "_blank"
            icon : "SomeURL"(Some custom icon from the project)
          }

          //renders icon
          {
            name: "App details",
            url: "http://msn.com",
            key: "key1",
            target: "_blank"
            icon : "Documentation"(Any Friendly Name from above list of icons)
          }
```

Requirement : Need to display an icon which is not part of list here https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try customize how your link looks like using the onRenderLink method

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav